# How to Combine multiple QHashes into one QHash

Tags: c++, qt, hash

I have two `QHash`es, and I want to combine them into one `QHash`.  Both hashes are of the same type (ie, both are `QHash<QString, qint32>`). How do I do this efficiently (and/or Qt-like)?

Something like:

```
hash1 << hash2;
```

or

```
hash1.append( hash2 );
```

or similar, would be awesome. If that's not possible, I'll just loop through the smaller hash and insert it into the first.

Comment: what do you mean by "combine"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [`QHash::unite()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#unite).

As stated in the linked documentation:

> **Inserts all the items in the other hash into this hash**. If a key is common to both hashes, the resulting hash will contain the key multiple times.

Comment: This function is now obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

The `unite` function has become obsolete as of Qt 5.15. The best solution is [`QHash::insert`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#insert-1).

Comment: Note that it may be relevant to point out the difference between both functions.